# Index of element in array F#

Tags: arrays, f#

Good day.

How to find index of the element in array? No word about it in docs. Only way I found is:

```
let arr = [|1; 4; 5; 10|]
let elem = 5
let i = Array.findIndex (fun e -> e = elem) arr
```

Comment: seems to me you answered your own question already - so what is the question?

Comment: I thought my method is a kludge and there is more elegant one.

Comment: you could reduce the lambda to `((=) elem)` and there is `Array.IndexOf` but basically those are just a matter of taste

Comment: Also consider `tryFindIndex` for those cases where you aren't 100 % sure that the element is in the array.

Comment: When you say 'kludge', do you mean 'inefficient' or do you mean 'ugly code'.  If you mean 'inefficient', then consider using Map with your elements as the key and index as the value, thus providing fast lookup of the index value [O(log N)].

Comment: In this case I mean 'ugly code' - creating lambda for iterating over array instead of using standard methods. But, based on comments, this is a normal approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a shortcut function yourself if you use it frequently:

```
let findIndex arr elem = arr |> Array.findIndex ((=) elem)
...
let i = findIndex arr elem
```

Comment: Or: let findIndex arr elem = arr |> Array.findIndex ((=) elem)

Comment: @Foole much more elegant. I'll incorporate it.